# T-SQL :: joining sys.masked_columns returns all columns in table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, data-masking

I'm trying to join `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and `sys.masked_columns` through `sys.objects`.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    TABLE_SCHEMA,
    TABLE_NAME, 
    COLUMN_NAME,
    DATA_TYPE
        + CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar', 'binary', 'varbinary')
                    AND CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH > 0 
                  THEN COALESCE('(' + CONVERT(varchar, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH) + ')', '')
                  ELSE '' 
          END
        + CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('decimal', 'numeric') 
                   THEN COALESCE('(' + CONVERT(varchar, NUMERIC_PRECISION) + ',' + CONVERT(varchar, NUMERIC_SCALE) + ')', '')
                   ELSE '' 
          END AS Declaration_Type,
    --CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE='NO' THEN 'NOT ' ELSE '' END + 'NULL' AS Nullable
    m.is_masked,
    m.masking_function 
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
JOIN
    sys.objects o ON c.table_name = o.name
JOIN 
    sys.masked_columns m ON o.[object_id] = m.[object_id] 
ORDER BY 
    1, 2, 3
```

and returns this:

| TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | Declaration_Type | is_masked | masking_function |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person | EmailAddress | BusinessEntityID | int | 1 | email() |
| Person | EmailAddress | EmailAddress | nvarchar(50) | 1 | email() |
| Person | EmailAddress | EmailAddressID | int | 1 | email() |
| Person | EmailAddress | ModifiedDate | datetime | 1 | email() |
| Person | EmailAddress | rowguid | uniqueidentifier | 1 | email() |

But the result is wrong because it shows that all columns in `Person.EmailAddress` are masked.

If I check through this query:

```
SELECT c.name, tbl.name as table_name, c.is_masked, c.masking_function  
FROM sys.masked_columns AS c  
JOIN sys.tables AS tbl   
    ON c.[object_id] = tbl.[object_id]  
WHERE is_masked = 1;
```

SSMS only return 1 masked column:

| name | table_name | is_masked | masking_function |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EmailAddress | EmailAddress | 1 | email() |  |

Why is returning every single column in the `Person.EmailAddress`?

Comment: Clearly it should also be joining on column_id not just object id. Otherwise how are you expecting the filtering of just the masked columns to happen? (though use `sys.columns` not `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` as that doesn't expose the id

Comment: Mixing `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` with the system views makes me a sad panda. Just don't use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` at all unless your intent is to write code that's (slightly) portable, which this isn't because masking is not a standard feature; these "standard" views are really only there as a compatibility layer and (on SQL Server, at least) not a very well implemented one at that.

Comment: Also means that you won't end up with buggy join conditions like `sys.objects o on c.table_name = o.name` which will be incorrect if the same named table exists in multiple schemas

Comment: Understood, thank you @JeroenMostert and MartinSmith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @MartinSmith and @JeroenMostert for their help in the comment.

The right solution was to get rid of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.*` columns and use `sys.` columns instead:

```
mc.name AS column_name, 
mc.is_masked, 
mc.masking_function
, [Type]         = 
    CASE 
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('varchar', 'char') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + IIF(mc.max_length = -1, 'max', CAST(mc.max_length AS VARCHAR(25))) + ')' 
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('nvarchar','nchar') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + IIF(mc.max_length = -1, 'max', CAST(mc.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(25)))+ ')'      
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('decimal', 'numeric') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + CAST(mc.[precision] AS VARCHAR(25)) + ', ' + CAST(mc.[scale] AS VARCHAR(25)) + ')'
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('datetime2') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + CAST(mc.[scale] AS VARCHAR(25)) + ')'
      ELSE tp.[name]
    END
FROM sys.masked_columns AS mc  
JOIN sys.tables AS tbl ON mc.[object_id] = tbl.[object_id]  
JOIN sys.types tp ON mc.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
WHERE mc.is_masked = 1;
```