# sys.types returns wrong data type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, types, data-masking, dynamic-data-masking

My goal is to script out and export Dynamic Data Masking.

In order to do so I have created a query that allows me to create the code dynamically:

```
SELECT 
schema_name(tbl.schema_id) AS schema_name,
tbl.name as table_name, 
mc.name AS column_name, 
mc.is_masked
, [Type]         = 
    CASE 
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('varchar', 'char') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + IIF(mc.max_length = -1, 'max', CAST(mc.max_length AS VARCHAR(25))) + ')' 
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('nvarchar','nchar') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + IIF(mc.max_length = -1, 'max', CAST(mc.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(25)))+ ')'      
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('decimal', 'numeric') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + CAST(mc.[precision] AS VARCHAR(25)) + ', ' + CAST(mc.[scale] AS VARCHAR(25)) + ')'
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('datetime2') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + CAST(mc.[scale] AS VARCHAR(25)) + ')'
      ELSE tp.[name]
    END,
mc.masking_function
,'ALTER TABLE '
+ schema_name(tbl.schema_id) + '.' + tbl.name +
' ALTER COLUMN '
+ mc.name +  ' ' + 
    CASE 
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('varchar', 'char') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + IIF(mc.max_length = -1, 'max', CAST(mc.max_length AS VARCHAR(25))) + ')' 
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('nvarchar','nchar') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + IIF(mc.max_length = -1, 'max', CAST(mc.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(25)))+ ')'      
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('decimal', 'numeric') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + CAST(mc.[precision] AS VARCHAR(25)) + ', ' + CAST(mc.[scale] AS VARCHAR(25)) + ')'
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('datetime2') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + CAST(mc.[scale] AS VARCHAR(25)) + ')'
      ELSE tp.[name]
    END
+ ' MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = ''' 

-- + mc.masking_function
+ CAST(mc.masking_function COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI AS nvarchar(100))
+ ''');'

FROM sys.masked_columns AS mc  
JOIN sys.tables AS tbl ON mc.[object_id] = tbl.[object_id]  
JOIN sys.types tp ON mc.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
WHERE mc.is_masked = 1;
```

The problem is that this code is half working as on AdventureWorks it returns me data type like `Name` or `Phone` that are not the actual data type of that column:

| schema_name | table_name | column_name | is_masked | Type | masking_function | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person | Person | FirstName | 1 | Name | partial(2, "xxxx", 0) | ALTER TABLE Person.Person ALTER COLUMN FirstName Name MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(2, "xxxx", 0)'); |
| Person | Person | LastName | 1 | nvarchar(50) | default() | ALTER TABLE Person.Person ALTER COLUMN LastName nvarchar(50) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()'); |
| Person | PersonPhone | PhoneNumber | 1 | Phone | partial(5, "XXXXXXX", 0) | ALTER TABLE Person.PersonPhone ALTER COLUMN PhoneNumber Phone MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(5, "XXXXXXX", 0)'); |
| Person | EmailAddress | EmailAddress | 1 | nvarchar(50) | email() | ALTER TABLE Person.EmailAddress ALTER COLUMN EmailAddress nvarchar(50) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'email()'); |

[image]

I had a query that was [working nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70096547/t-sql-joining-sys-masked-columns-returns-all-columns-in-table) but it was joining `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and `sys.*` tables and this is not best practice.

Why some data type are prefixed with `Name` or `Phone`?

How to target the right data type for each column?

Comment: It looks like you are using "user defined data types" which is the datatype you are being returned. Which would be the correct behaviour in my opinion.

Comment: I hope you never need to change those data types; you'll be in for a world of hurt I'm  afraid.

Comment: @DaleK, I have no `Phone` or `Name` hardcoded, is picking it up from  `sys.types`. But I don't see any other column in  `sys.types` that could return me `nvarchar(50)` so if I don't take that data type from `sys.types` where should I take it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the query to return the system data type `nvarchar(50)` (instead of the user-defined data type `Name`), you should change the JOIN with `sys.types` this way:

```
JOIN sys.types tp ON tp.user_type_id = mc.system_type_id
```